# simple sql query for inserting data in database

Tags: sql

I am working on the transaction with databases.

I want to write a sql query which will insert only those numbers which are starting from 101.

```
sql = "insert into tablex (data) where values (101123)";
sql = "insert into tablex (data) where values (10100)";  
sql = "insert into tablex (data) where values (101125)";
```

All inserts should happnd with values which starts with 101 only.
It should not enter other values like :

```
sql = "insert into tablex (data) where values (105232)";
```

the numbers 101123, 10100, 101123, 105232 comes from a text file with some program.
I want to only insert those numbers which starts with 101 in table.

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: i am having trouble while checking the condition. i only want to insert those numbers which starts from 101 and i want to give error all other numbers or skipping it.

Comment: Filter out the ones that shouldn't be inserted at the application level. Don't put that burden on your SQL code.

Comment: filter your data before calling sql to see if it contains 101 and then decide whether to call sql or not. Your code above doesn't make sense or help us determine how you are reading data and calling sql

Comment: which data do you want to insert, which type of database are you using ? Syntax for an insert is: Insert tablex(colname1, colname2) values (val1, val2)

Comment: @rs : yes brother i just want to know how to filter

Comment: @sam can you post your current code

Comment: @rs :  i have a text file from which I am reading numbers and then I AM passing those to sql queries for insert. i jus want to insert those numbers which can have 101 at start in db

Comment: how are you reading file using C# or VB.NET or php etc?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you want to filter using `LIKE` ([SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e79a0/1))

```
insert into yourtable (col1)
select yourColumn
from yourtable
where yourColumn LIKE '101%'
```